# Does SAS allow ORDER BY in a CREATE statement?

Tags: sas

I tried to `ORDER` a table while creating it, but then noticed that SAS does not allow it . Here is the code

```
proc sql;
create table test as (
select * 
from sashelp.class
order by name);
quit;
```

Here are the errors that I get :

```
1383  order by name);
      -----
      79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).

1383! order by name);
                   -
                   79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a (.
```

I can certainly use `proc sort` but I read the `CREATE TABLE` documentation and did not find any restrictions placed on `ORDER BY` other than it is not recommended . [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002294522.htm) lists the `create . . order by` as a valid syntax . So what is the problem here ?

By The Way . . simple `select . . order by` works fine

```
proc sql;
select * 
from sashelp.class
order by name;
quit;*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select * 
from sashelp.class
order by name;
quit;
```

Not sure why SAS doesn't like them - I think it's because they are for subqueries only, which technically this isn't.  At any rate you do not need them.

Comment: In SAS, Order By is only allowed in the main outer query; you aren't allowed to do order by in subqueries.  That is different from many SQL implementations, which allow for ordering in subqueries.

Comment: Thanks. in fact according to the syntax http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002294522.htm there are no parenthesis in the create statement

Comment: The parentheses aren't specifically wrong, they just make it a subquery to the parser (which means it can't have an order by), as sparc noted.